# People picker can not show trusted domain users

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker, trusted-domain

I have two domains in my company DomainA and DomainB. DomainA has one way trust with DomainB. SharePoint 2010 is installed on DomainA.

My problem is that my users have to log in once to Portal so that SharePoint people picker can show their name. What should I do to see all of my users in DomainB even if they have not logged in to SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use STSADM utility for configuring people picker control.

In your case following command enable people picker control to query one-way trust with another forest or domain.

```
STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:DomainA;domain:DomainB,domainB\Account,password"
```

More on configuring people picker in One Way Trust Environment

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rkramesh/archive/2010/08/18/configuring-people-picker-in-one-way-trust-environment.aspx
http://www.pointbeyond.com/2012/06/08/sharepoint-2010-and-one-way-trusts-it-works-fine

Comment: This did not solve my problem. Users still must log in at least once so that people picker can show their users.